# How to register mouse event from a different class

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

I have a class which trying to register an event in another class.

In class A I have a method as shown below:

```
 public void Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I am registering the event in class B like so:

```
            ClassA classA = new ClassA();
            classA.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(classA.Mouse_Down);
```

When click nothing is happening. Does anyone know what the problem could be.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the `Mouse_Down` method?

Comment: Looks like there is typo in your question in second code snippet's second line you may want to use **this** keyword rather than classA at start?

Comment: yes i have. it never entered the method. any ideas?

Comment: What is the base class of ClassA? Is it a Form or a container control? If so, does it contain any other controls?

Comment: @Maheep Tried it too, but didnt work!

Comment: @Stephan It's a PictureBox. Does not contain any other components.

Comment: Can you please paste code of class B where this code is written. Is that code being executed? Try putting breakpoint in class B code to see if its being hit.

Comment: You never added the picture box to the form's Controls collection so it isn't visible and can't be clicked.  It is also very unusual to have a control listen for its *own* events.  Override OnMouseDown() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a breakpoint at the event triggering code (of classA) and check your EventHandlers collection. I bet there is no one registered and you're messing with classA instances.

It is also possible that you will never get your breakpoint, which means that your event is not fired.

Anyway the thing that you want to do looks a little weird for me.

**Edit:**

Have you tried to register a different method to the same event 'in normal way' (ex. from a ClassA constructor)? If you don't have access to event triggering code, that is to best way to check if there are proper handlers registered, at the moment of event being fired.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to handle the event raised by `ClassB`:

You are registering the event for `ClassA`'s event, not `ClassB`'s. The fact that you're doing it from class b doesn't mean anything.

---

Assuming you do want to handle the event raised by `ClassA`:

One possibility is that a different instance of `ClassA` is triggering the event, not the one who's event is handled.

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
```

The above creates a new instance of classA. If it's not this one that raises an event, then you won't get your method called.